# Update Data in one webpage and displayed in other webpage

Tags: node.js

I need to update data(new offers or any other information) in a webpage. This update must be done by client and update must be displayed in the same webpage.
  For eg: webpage called `mirror.com` and other webpage called `mirror.com/update-`
here,client will input  data in `mirror.com/update` page and it must be `displayed/updated` in `mirror.com` page.

I'm using `nodejs`

Comment: Well we have the spec, but you dont mention how much you are going to pay for our time!

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
___Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you___

Comment: If you're using node.js then why did you use the [tag:php] tag?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for real time updates? Then you have to use a Websocket connection.

You can use [socket.io](http://socket.io), [sockjs](https://github.com/sockjs) or pusher.com for this. In the nodejs community , many people use socket.io. you can easily implement it into your project.

You have to build your own websocket server for socket.io and sockjs, but you don't want to do that when you use pusher. But socket.io, sockjs is much faster than pusher as i know. Because of when you use pusher , you have to connect to pusher server and grab the data back and then again you have to connect your own sever to display the data. But when you use socket.io or sockjs, you are working with the same sever.